# Lodash filter through all values in a object

Tags: javascript, object, filter, key, lodash

I'm using Lodash to filter an object.

```
var search = 180;
var filterBy = "other_num";

var items = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 1',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 183,
  date: '05/04/2018'
}, {
  id: 2,
  name: 'Amanda',
  num: 250,
  other_num: 180,
  date: '12/03/2018'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 3',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 211,
  date: '02/03/2018'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 4',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 211,
  date: '02/03/2018'
}, ];

var filtered = _.filter(items, function(item) {
  return (item[filterBy].toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1);
});

console.log(filtered);
```

As you can see, I've setted `search` and `filterBy` vars. But instead of "filter by" some key, I was wondering if it's possible to find the value of `search` in any key.

Something like this:

```
var filtered = _.filter(items, function(item) {
  return (item.id.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1) || (item.name.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1) || (item.num.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1) || (item.other_num.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1) || (item.date.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toString().toLowerCase()) > -1);
});
```

Although the **code above works** (see [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ericgruby/7dsfje1g/) and check the console), it's not dynamic nor reusable. I mean, if it's needed to add/remove keys, I would have to manually add/remove directives from the `return`.

Any thoughts on how to make this **smarter** and **reusable**? Am I missing some Lodash functionality?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But instead of "filter by" some key, I was wondering if it's possible
>   to find the value of search in **any key**.

*Vanilla JS solution* - try `Object.values`

```
var search = 180;
var output = items.filter( s => Object.values( s ).includes( search ) );
```

**Demo**

```js
var search = 180;

var items = [{
  id: 180, //changed for the purpose of testing
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 1',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 183,
  date: '05/04/2018'
}, {
  id: 2, 
  name: 'Amanda',
  num: 250,
  other_num: 180,
  date: '12/03/2018'
}, {
  id: 3,
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 3',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 211,
  date: '02/03/2018'
}, {
  id: 4,
  name: 'Fulano da Silva 4',
  num: 300,
  other_num: 211,
  date: '02/03/2018'
}];
var output = items.filter( s => Object.values( s ).includes( search ) );
console.log( output );
```

Comment: Cool! Your answer is correct. Now I have to find a way to make it work on Vue.js, once the user will enter the `search` term. You see, [the filter works](https://jsfiddle.net/ericgruby/cwz2fybq/) when I put **exactly** "Amanda", "Fulano da Silva 1", or any _exact_ string. It doesn't work when I input "250" because there's no such _string_ on the values. I think it's better to ask a new question. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry for the double comment xD I just changed the return to this `return app.items.filter( s => Object.values( s ).toString().toLowerCase().indexOf( app.search ) > -1 );` and it worked as expected. I'm really thankful for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

what about (es6):

```
_.filter(items, { [filterBy]: search });
```